# Running a specific program when the system is idle, and terminating it on user input

Tags: linux, ubuntu, screensaver, kiosk

I have a number of Ubuntu "Kiosk" systems that people can walk up to and use to access a specific website to enter specific information. As is, the screens go blank after 5 minutes of non-use. I would however like to change this behavior.

My organization runs a digital signage application called XIBO, which has a Ubuntu client. I would like the systems to run that instead of blanking the screens when the kiosks haven't been used for 5 minutes. I'd prefer to use the Ubuntu XIBO application since I have a lot of installations and I want to synchronize content using that system.

I looked into programs like xscreensaver to do this, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to accomplish this. Just finding idle time and doing something seems to be a bit of struggle.

Am I missing some obvious methods to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with the methods of your session manager / desktop environment; things like systemd-timers etc simply won't have access to all the environments necessary to start graphical applications.

Thus, your screensaver approach is good!

Assuming this is a Ubuntu running GNOME, you'd want to *not* show a screen saver, yet still use the gnome-screensaver environment.

Then, you'd write a quick [dbus monitor that looks  for session inactivity](https://wiki.gnome.org/Attic/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Is_there_a_way_to_perform_actions_when_the_screensaver_activates_or_deactivates.3F_Or_when_the_session_becomes_idle.3F), and react accordingly (whatever that means in terms of XIBO.

I bet XIBO itself also has a screensaver mode, so you could possibly also just modify your ~/.xscreensaver in some way, but I have absolutely no clue about XIBO.